# How to merge query from 2 tables and group it in JSON Array on WCF Service?

Tags: sql-server, json, wcf

I have 2 tables on my `SQL Server` Database and I want to merge then in 1 JSON Array on my WCF Service.

Table1:

```
----------------
| type | total |
----------------
|   A  |   2   |
|   B  |   3   |
|   C  |   4   |
----------------
```

Table2:

```
----------------
| type | total |
----------------
|   A  |   5   |
|   B  |   6   |
|   C  |   7   |
----------------
```

and I want my JSON Array like this:

```
{"GetResult":
        [
          {"table1":
               [
                 {"type":"A", "total":"2"},
                 {"type":"B", "total":"3"},
                 {"type":"C", "total":"4"}
               ]
          },
          {"table2":
               [
                 {"type":"A", "total":"5"},
                 {"type":"B", "total":"6"},
                 {"type":"C", "total":"7"}
               ]
          }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert your datatable to `JSONArray`. This [link](http://rpnc-shivanjali.blogspot.in/2012/04/convert-datatable-to-jsonarray-in-net.html) will help you.

Then you need to combine the json array's using `JavaScript` as done in [Combining JSON arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822079/combining-json-arrays)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You can create your data contract like

```
[DataContract]
public class ResultData
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<DataItem> Table1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<DataItem> Table2 { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class DataItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Total{ get; set; }

}
```

and then add service contract as

```
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/ResultData", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 ResultData GetJsonData();
```